# Single and double quote issue in SQL insert

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

Please see the query below.

```
INSERT INTO pro VALUES ("260915",'Peel and Stick Floral Wall Art','Transform your tot's bedroom into a bright, burgeoning meadow with this set of oh-so-colorful wall art. Each unique flower, bird, butterfly, and swirly sun is a colorful creation of multilayered vinyl brimming with life and energy. How best to arrange them is entirely up to you--and your 12.2" x 15.4"','','Shipping',"790","110-m4jlgu36n",1.00,0,0,"0.00","70.00","http://.com/peel-and-stick-floral-wall-art.html","622")
```

Here I have single quote and double quote in same value which I want to insert in a column:

```
eg a) 12.2" x 15.4"
   b) Transform your tot's
```

Please suggest best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building the `INSERT`, use single quotes in the outside and the problem with double quotes is solved.

To fix the problem with single quotes, replace `'` by `''`.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't escape your quotes? `12.2\"` ?

Comment: i cant because it is coming from server and i need to insert same in database

Comment: If it's coming from the server, then you don't need to worry about them do you?

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside single quote `'`

```
'12.2" x 15.4"<br>'
```

for string like this `Transform your tot's` you will have to escape it like

```
'Transform your tot\'s'
```

Answer (score 0):

For T-SQL, to get a single quote in your data you just escape it with another (e.g. use two single quotes next to each other)  You don't need to worry about double quotes inside the string literals.

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('qwerty''s: 25" sq.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only single quote (') to surround the values. If a single quote is part of the value, type it in twice (that is the way to escape it).

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('12.2" x 15.4"', 'Transform your tot''s bedroom...');
```